# I have enough stack space for my array, so why does this loop fail?

Tags: c++

```
int width = 2560;
int height = 1440;
int frameBuffer[width*height];
for (int i = 0; i < width*height; ++i)
    frameBuffer[i]=i;
```

This code locks the process up, even thou I am well within the bounds of 32 bit integers and I have plenty of memory to allocate the array?

BTW Ironic, isn't it? Asking about a stack overflow error on a site called stackoverflow :)

Comment: stack allocation of variable-length arrays (`int frameBuffer[width*height];`) is allowed in C99, but it is not valid C++. In C++11 however you can declare `width` and `height` with the `constexpr` keyword. In traditional C++ use dynamic allocation!

Comment: Duplicate of loads of questions

Comment: the size of the array not being const was my first thought but adding a const variable for the total size did not fix it, and I think arithmetics that are not contained within a variable are treated as const, just like hardcoded "" strings are treated as const

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably exceeding the available stack space, causing an overflow. It is not a good idea to have such big arrays on the stack.

Instead of using the non-standard VLA's (variable-length arrays), you can allocate the buffer yourself:

```
size_t width = 2560;
size_t height = 1440;
int *frameBuffer = new int[width * height];

for (size_t i = 0; i < width * height; ++i)
    frameBuffer[i] = i;

...
delete[] frameBuffer;
```

Also note the usage of `size_t` rather than `int`. You should stick with `size_t` when it comes to allocation sizes, since an `int` is not always guaranteed to be capable of holding a size large enough.

Comment: Makes sense, will try to slap it onto the heap to see how it goes. BTW is there a way to determine how big the stack is?

Comment: @ddriver: The web has search facilities, and with them I found this -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693842/is-there-any-way-to-determine-the-available-stack-space-at-run-time

Comment: Better still, use `std::vector<int>` so that it's automatically deallocated after use, even if an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 3):

The way you declare it, the array is probably allocated on the  stack (I am not sure though). You should try to allocate it dynamically, ideally using an `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> frameBuffer(width * height);
```

Answer (score 0):

the number of elements the array is going to hold, must be a constant value, since arrays are blocks of non-dynamic memory whose size must be determined before execution. In order to create arrays with a variable length dynamic memory is needed

use `int frameBuffer[2560*1440];`